# How to read specific content between two node from XML file using VBScript

Tags: xml, vbscript

My XML file contains many `<authentication...></authentication>` nodes, and I want to read the content of the file which is in between `<authentication name="allow-list">` to `</authentication>` nodes.

Can someone please tell me how to do this? How to start to read the file from `<authentication name=allow-list">` node using VBScript?

test.xml file contains:

```xml
<?xml ...?>
<authentication name="deny-list">
  <selector>
  </selector>
</authentication>
<authentication name="allow-list">
  <selector>
  </selector>
</authentication>
```

and I tried the following code. I'm able to get the selector values but not able to read from `<authentication name="allow-list">`.

```vb
Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile("sample.xml", ForAppending, True)

strFile = "test.xml"

strOld = "<selector>"
strNew = "<selector>"
strSelClose = "</selector>"

strOrg = strNew
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
i = 0
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine 
    If InStr(strLine, strOld) > 0 Then
        i = i + 1
        strNew = strOrg
        filetxt.WriteLine(strLine)
    End If

    If InStr(strLine, strSelClose) > 0 Then 
        filetxt.WriteLine(strLine)
    End If
```

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx).

Comment: can you please provide me the sample code

Comment: Did you actually read the page I linked to?

Comment: Your XML is broken, your VBScript is incomplete, and you obviously didn't read any of the documentation I referred you to.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `<authentication name="allow-list">` and `</authentication` are always on separate lines, just do something like this (if that condition doesn't apply let me know, and I'll adjust the code):

```vb
authStart = "<authentication"
authEnd = "</authentication>"
isInFileSection = False ' keeps track if the current line is between a start and end authentication tag

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    If isInFileSection Then
        If InStr(strLine, authEnd) = 0 then
            filetxt.WriteLine strLine
        Else
            isInFileSection = False
        End If
    Else
        If InStr(strLine, authStart) > 0 Then
            isInFileSection = True
        End If
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: You need to assign False to isInFileSection when/after reading authEnd. Blunders like this show that you should use proper tools (here: XML parser) instead of trying to roll your own.

Comment: Since the data is XML the tags are *not* guaranteed to always be on different lines. Using string matches for processing XML data structures is practically always a bad idea. Don't do this.